# How to use Grunt without compressing everything into a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt for the first time.  Someone else has already setup/configured the `Gruntfile.js` configuration file.  Although it works, what I find incredibly annoying is that all my js files are reduced into a single app.min.js file with a map file.

So even though this works, when I get an error or a bug, it is impossible to know which source file caused the JS bug.

Is there a way to configure Grunt not to compress everything into a single file, but to leave everything as separate includes?  I love the ability to only need to include a single JS in my html.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jsFilesApis: [
        'client/vendors/apis/jquery-1.11.0.min.js',
        'client/vendors/apis/bootstrap.min.js',
        'client/vendors/apis/angular.1.2.16.min.js',
        .....
        ],
    jsFilesApp: [
        'client/app/**/*.js'
    ],


    'angular-injector': {
        test: {
            expand: true,       // required
            token: 'ng',        // optional
            src: '<%= jsFilesApp %>',
            dest: 'build/'
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                "build/app.min.js": '<%= jsFilesApp %>',
                "build/apis.min.js": '<%= jsFilesApis %>'
            },
            options: {
                mangle: false,
                compress: false,
                sourceMap: true
            }
        },
    },
});
```

An my HTML is:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/apis.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./build/app.min.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

How do I configure Grunt such that I can have all my JS files separately included to be able to view/debug them appropriately in the browser?

Comment: I am just guessing. but what if you remove the declaration for `uglify`?

Comment: @jdphenix Then I would have to list all the JS dependency files one by one in my html wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JakeDluhy gave me a good suggestion and some pointers in the right direction.  I ended up using [`grunt-injector`](https://github.com/klei/grunt-injector) combined with bower/wiredep to get what I needed.  Final trick was to use `yeoman` to generate a scaffold AngularJS file and steal ideas from the generated Gruntfile.js.

Now in my index.html I have the following:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js(client/) scripts/apis.js -->
<!-- api injector:js -->
<script src="vendors/apis/http-auth-interceptor.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/apis/ng-tags-input.js"></script>
<!-- endinjector -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js(client/) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- app injector:js -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/breadcrumb/breadcrumbController.js"></script>
<!-- endinjector -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And my Gruntfile.js:

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  options: {
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },

// Automatically inject app JS files into the app
injector:{
    app:{
        options:{
            starttag: '<!-- app injector:{{ext}} -->',
            ignorePath: 'client/',
            addRootSlash: false
        },
        files:{
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html' : ['<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*.js']
        }
    },

    api:{
        options: {
            starttag: '<!-- api injector:{{ext}} -->',
            ignorePath: 'client/',
            addRootSlash: false
        },
        files:{
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html' : ['<%= yeoman.app %>/vendors/**/*.js']
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, there's no way to only include a single script tag with all of your javascript, while keeping them separate in your source.
I do not know of a grunt plugin or otherwise that will concat your javascripts into a single script but allow you to see them separately in the browser (a la sprockets).

However, what I have is a non-minified script (in development) that I can look at. It does not show you immediately what library, or file it is from, but you can at least see the code.

What I have is (using `grunt-contrib-concat`)

```
concat: {
        'build/<%= pkg.name %>.js': ['build/vendor.js', 'build/app.js', 'build/templates.js']
    },
```

which for you would be something like

```
concat: {
     "build/app.js": '<%= jsFilesApp %>',
     "build/apis.js": '<%= jsFilesApis %>'
},
```

And then include both of those in your html. You'll also want to specify not to uglify on a development build. For me, this look like

```
grunt.registerTask('build:dev', ['clean:dev', 'browserify:app', 'browserify:test', 'emberTemplates', 'jshint:dev', 'less:transpile', 'concat', 'copy:dev']);
```

So for you it would be

```
grunt.registerTask('build:dev', ['angular-injector', 'concat']);
grunt.registerTask('build:prod', ['angular-injector', 'concat', 'uglify']);
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  Definitely helps make this easier, although still not 100% ideal.  I think something like an angular directive that would be able to automatically insert all the <script>..</script> tags in the html would be amazing, where the directive would be based on data coming from Grunt (ie: `<%=jsFilesApp%>` expanded), but that is way outside something I can figure out right now.

Comment: That's a cool idea. Just a simple search gave me this https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-script-link-tags. I haven't gotten a chance to try it out but it seems like it would work. Or a bit more general https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-injector

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I ended up using grunt-injector and it does exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.